# How to get text colors back for VS Community ScrollBar MapMode

Tags: visual-studio, scrollbar, visual-studio-2022, mapmode

As of today my MapMode Scrollbar in VS Community 2022 doesn't have color highlighting anymore:

[image: Text]

It used to show the comments in green, strings in orangebrown, etc. Now it's suddenly all white making it more tedious to navigate through long code.

I've already tried to update to the latest preview version as well as revert to my last installed version. Reinstalling VS, rebooting, etc. all had no effect either.

Has anybody else come across this problem and managed to solve it?